# Spark Streaming 2.3.1 Type Casting: String to Timestamp

Tags: apache-spark, casting, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am using apsche spark streaming 2.3.1, where I am receiving a stream containing a timestamp values (13:09:05.761237147) of the format "HH:mm:ss.xxxxxxxxx" as string.

I am in need to cast this string to timestamp data type.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("abc") \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType().add("timestamp", "string").add("object", "string").add("score", "double")

lines = spark \
    .readStream \
    .option("sep", ",") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .csv("/path/to/folder/")
```

Any suggestion how to convert "timestamp" to timestamp data type?

Comment: `lines.withColumn('timestamp' col('timestamp').cast('timestamp'))` ? Since you don't have any date associated, I believe it will take today's date in the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

As per the description provided in source code of TimestampType and DateTimeUtils classes, they support timestamps till microseconds precision only.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.scala

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/DateTimeUtils.scala